# React | Mantine lib | Dropdown menu moves and focuses you on the menu. How to prevent these moves?

Tags: css, reactjs, mantine

The dropdown menu moves and focuses you on the menu. How to prevent these moves?

Take a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mantine-autofocus-menu-vmb23q?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=410&resolutionHeight=224), please

Make the height of a screen less than the height of an open menu and open it, you'll notice that you move to your menu, from the header to the menu. What if I don't want to move and focus on the menu? How to work this case out?